# CCS change fore color onfocus / onblur

Tags: jquery, css

my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TOTAL" 
onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = '';  this.ForeColor = black; }"
onblur="if (this.value == '')  this.value = this.defaultValue; this.css('color', 'LightGray');" 
style="text-align: center;" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="60px" ForeColor="LightGray">8</asp:TextBox>
```

I'm trying:

```
this.css('color', 'LightGray')
```

or

```
this.ForeColor = black
```

or

```
this.ForeColor = 'black'
```

doesnt work, I dont wants use jQ like:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
 if($(this).val() == this.defaultValue){$(this).val('');$(this).css("color","green");}
}).blur(function(){
 if($(this).val() == ''){$(this).val(this.defaultValue);$(this).css("color","grey");}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.classname{color:grey}
.classname:focus, .clasname:active { color:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.style.color`.

Not sure it it will work cross-browser/cross-(old)-version, which is what jQuery in general solves for you, but apparantly you are against that...

Answer (score 0):

@Peter B thanks you, working ;)

SOLUTION:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TOTAL" onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = ''; this.style.color = 'black'; }"
         onblur="if (this.value == '' || this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = this.defaultValue; this.style.color = 'LightGray'; }" style="text-align: center;" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="60px" ForeColor="LightGray">8</asp:TextBox>
```